# angular js ng repeat asynchronously

Tags: angularjs

I want to show a list of elements on view asynchronously.
For example i have a method which returns promise and result will look like this.

```
var result = {
    books: [
        {name: 'The Kite Runner', author: 'Khaled Hosseini'},
        {name: 'The Book Thief', author: 'Markus Zusak'},
        {name: 'A Thousand Splendid Suns', author: 'Khaled Hosseini'},
    ]
}
```

Here is a method:

```
function getBooks(userId) {
    return BookProduct.getBooksByUser.query({ id: userId }).$promise;
};
```

And then i have a method which invokes `getBooks`.

```
$scope.showBooks = function(userId) {
    //some users id
    var users_id = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $scope.tables = [];
    for (i = 0; i < users_id.length; i++) {
        getBooks(i).then(function(result){
           $scope.table = {
               books = result;
           } 
            $scope.tables.push($scope.table);
        })
    }
}
```

Thereafter i want to show it to user on a view using angular `ng-repeat`.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="table in tables">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Author</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="book in table.books">
                <td>{{ name }}</td>
                <td>{{ author }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

It works good but ng-repeat will work when function `$scope.showBooks` is executed and `$scope.tables` is already full. I am looking for more nice solution. I want to load books for user piecemeal on each iteration when method `getBooks()` invokes.

So in this part for example when the first iteration is processing and i get result of 2 elements, then i pass them to the view and user can see the first part. Next iteration i get for example other 3 elements, so i add them to previous result and pass to the view, so user can see 5 elements now, and so on. I know it will be almost insensibly for user but if my server responds slowly it will help me to be more user friendly.

```
for (i = 0; i < users_id.length; i++) {
            getBooks(i).then(function(result){
               $scope.table = {
                   books = result;
               } 
                $scope.tables.push($scope.table);
            })
        }
```

I am not asking you HOW to implement it. I just want to know is it possible or not and where should i dig to know more, cause i tried some googling but without success.

Comment: What about a spinner while stuff gets loaded?

Comment: I think $apply will help you.

Comment: diegoaguilar i am planning to use spinner but between parts, when request is sending to server

Comment: Can you create two different arrays? Like one for the ng-repeat (Array A) and another one for the data you just received from the server (Array B). When the request is made, add the data to the array B and afterwards add the objects that in in array B but not in Array A? Clean up the array B after successfully merge the two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a cycle in which it performs all scope functionality and after each cycle of "watches" it renders changes to the view. By default, Angular performs this automatically - for example simple change of variable in scope also rerenders view. But in some cases you may want to intercept because your operation didn't trigger the rerender.

For these cases, $apply and $digest are useful - more in documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply